# What types of constraints can I have in UML and when would I use them?

Tags: uml

I came across the default constraints in EA Sparx and was wondering what other constraints can I have e.g. Assumptions and when would I use them?

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/modeling_fundamentals/constrainttypes.html

For example how would I define the inability to gather logs or there is a single point of failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints in Models are not part of standard UML. They are normally created using either the [Object Constraint Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language) (which you can run tests against) or in plain text.

OCL is an add-on to UML. From my experience, however, the OCL support in contemporary CASE tools like EA or MagicDraw is rather basic. The [OCL specs](http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.3.1/PDF/) define the various possible constraints (see p. 175 ff.).
So you can use a constraint for annotating conditions to your model elements which you assume to be met at runtime.